# Question about the use of the word "goal" with prepositions

Tags: prepositions

He has yet to achieve his goal ______ the company on a sound financial footing.

a) by establishing
b) with establishing
c) of establishing
d) on establishing

Why the correct answer is b) instead of c)?

Comment: I agree that c is correct. From where does this question come? I have read that some of the English language teaching sites and books contain errors.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to imagine (b) being the correct answer. Answer (c) is idiomatic and makes sense: we often pair "goal" with "of," as in "I have a goal of walking a mile." Answer (a) also shows a common pairing: I might accomplish my goal *by* walking for half an hour. It could also make some sense, but is a less obvious choice than (c), since if "establishing the company" is a *way* to achieve his goal, then the sentence would not say exactly what his goal is.